Cursor.ai not seeing python interpreters/kernels
I am trying out the copilot-driven IDE cursor.ai as a potential replacement for vscode. However, it appears unable to find all of the python interpreters/envs I have installed on my Mac (running Sonoma). It seems to only find global python interpreters and only 1 of the 7 virtualenvs I have installed. Has anyone else experienced this or found a fix?
